# Error 500 when running an inside system function on JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Friends, I'm trying to collect some system time on JMeter.

There is a requisition like below:
[image]

The StartDateTime is collected (into the system), using the following function:
**RoomBoardStartLogProcess()**

And the EndDateTime using the following: **RoomBoardEndLogProcess()**

How can I execute them inside the JMeter? The syntax ${__func()} is showing error 500 into the HTTP Request

*This time is **different** than the current UTC time. It's not the "${__javaScript((new Date()).toISOString())}"*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `RoomBoardEndLogProcess()` is a [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) function specific to your web application you cannot invoke this using [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as it's simply not implemented.

You need to inspect the function code and come up with the equivalent somewhere in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and better using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). Once you generate the value you can store it into a JMeter Variable and use the variable as the request parameter.